# What is the difference between "so far" and "yet"?

Tags: differences, present-perfect

I would like to know the difference between *so far* and *yet*.

> I have not sent two invitations *so far*.
>
> I have not sent two invitations *yet*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> - *I have not sent two invitations **yet**.*
> - *I have not sent two invitations **so far**.*

The major difference is that *yet* is a [Negative Polarity Item (NPI)](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A15299%20negative%20polarity%20item), while *so far* isn't.
The way you demonstrate that is to remove the *not* from both sentences:

- *I have sent two invitations so far*
  is still grammatical, but
- **I have sent two invitations yet*
  **isn't** grammatical (hence the *), because [an NPI can't occur without a negative to trigger it](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf).

Comment: Yet another case which has yet to find its negative trigger.

Answer (score 1):

"yet" must be used with negative or interrogative negative sentences but 
"so far" is used with affirmative sentences.

> Hasn't she completed her studies yet?
>   Mohan hasn't eaten dinner yet?
>   Many applications have been invited but a few has been submitted so far.